# change style of cell when the values are not correlatives

Tags: jquery, css

here's the thing, the bills came out from a dot matrix printer, and the paper is in continous format (like mos of you guys may saw in a sales department). Sometimes to cover a sale, the salesman take a bill (not printed a blank one) to make it by hand.
the system as it is now, can handle this jumps by letting people set the value by hand and then it continues incrementing the value.

but htere's a gap left, I have to highlight the row (just the cell with the id) before the gap, just to make more visible the fact that someone took a bill, made it by hand and haven't reguistered yet.

it's like this:
(the css class for the id column is clave, meaning key)

```
|  id | qtty | price |
|-----+------+-------+
| 001 |   25 |     3 |
| 002 |   35 |     5 |
| 004 |   86 |     3 |
| 005 |   96 |     1 |
| 007 |   85 |     2 |
| 008 |   24 |     1 |
```

so the row for id 002 and 005 should be presented with font-weight: bold css, to make more spotable the missing bills.
the other problem I have is that this html structure is not a table, it is actually made of layers (div tags).

I have tghis much of the code, I don't know why it isn't working...
and youi can see it running here:
[in this JSbin](http://jsbin.com/isaruj/2)

Comment: in your example link, there is an error on the page that says jquery is not defined. Make sure this page has access to jquery before you continue, maye reference the google copy. <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: File reference issue.. Include the jQuery file

Comment: I corrected the refencer problem, but it stills doesn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long time looking at your explanation I think this is what you want to do

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".clave").each(function(i, v) { // loop through each elem with class=clave
        var $next = $.trim($(".clave").eq(i + 1).text()); // get next text
        var $ele = $.trim($(v).text()); // get this text
        if ((+$next) - (+$ele) > 1) { // subtract next from now - if greateer than 1
            $(v).css('color', 'red').css('font-weight','bold'); // turn current text bold
        };
    });
});​
```

EDIT:
Forgot to use $.trim() instead of .trim() for cross browser support

http://jsfiddle.net/Zxc2w/

http://jsbin.com/isaruj/5/

Comment: trim!
I wouldn't ever thought  of using trim here :O

Comment: Just trimming the unnecessary whitespace :)  I noticed there was a lot of whitespace inside for some reason

Comment: can you take the time to explain me the function(i,v)...
where did you get 2 variables???

Comment: Inside the each function.. the first argument = the index of the current element inside the collection.. so you can do i+1 to get the next element and compare.. v contains your DOM Element - which is the td element.. and you can turn it into a jQuery object again to use jQuery functions.  It's just like a for loop.. where i is the index.. but jQuery passes in the element as an argument also.. You can read more about it here http://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: thnx, I would use a mopre simplistic approach but I can't get my hands into de PHP...

Comment: dude is it possible to avoid having conflicts with mootools, I just find Out that some code is using mootools, so at the integration, both fails.

Comment: @MarcosVargasMoran Yes.. read more about it here http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17627/discussion-between-marcos-vargas-moran-and-wirey)

Answer (score 1):

One approach to the problem:

```
function ensureConsecutive(el) {
    if (!el || !el.parentNode.nextElementSibling) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        var curId = parseInt(el.textContent,10),
            parent = el.parentNode,
            nextRow = parent.nextElementSibling,
            nextId = parseInt(nextRow
            .getElementsByClassName('id')[0].textContent,10);

        if (curId + 1 !== nextId) {
            $(el).addClass('nonConsecutive');
        }
    }
}

$('td.id').each(
    function(i,el){
        ensureConsecutive(el);
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/VbnPV/1/).

Though this is not cross-browser compatible, due to the `nextElementSibling` and `textContent` use, this could become cross-browser using a more jQuery approach or through alternate plain-JavaScript methods (`innerText` for one).

Answer (score 0):

use a jQuery selector, then iterate through all selected and use the .css method to change the css